# What does the url /echo/json/ in this jsfiddle do?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsfiddle

I have no confusion about the code below, I just do not understand what kind of url this is:  `/echo/json/`.

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Y2WUN/335/).

You can see that data getting posted to this url `/echo/json/` but this url probably does not exist. So tell me how this url `/echo/json/` is working.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/echo/json/',
  data: {
    json: ko.toJSON(entries),
    delay: .1
  },
  success: function(entries) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(entries, function(entry) {
      viewModel.items.push(entry);
    });
    viewModel.pendingRequest(false);
  },
  error: function() {
    viewModel.pendingRequest(false);
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

The only issue I have is about this url `/echo/json/`, I'd like to know how it is working.

Comment: This is a feature of JSFiddle: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: ohh the sorry i was not aware

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506876/what-does-the-url-echo-json-in-this-jsfiddle-do#comment49089465_30506876) pointed out in the comments, this is a feature of JSFiddle.

[The JSFiddle docs](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests) provide these URLs (`/echo/html`, `/echo/json`, `/echo/jsonp`, `/echo/xml`, and `/echo/js`) as stubs which simply echo back the given data. You can use this to emulate a response with an optionally-specified delay, which would be useful for testing a nonexistent REST action or AJAX call handler of some sort, for example.

The format for using the JSON URL from raw Javascript is as follows (ripped from their example page):

```
new Request.JSON({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.encode({
            text: 'some text',
            array: [1, 2, 'three'],
            object: {
                par1: 'another text',
                par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
                par3: {}
            }
        }),
        delay: 3
    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        show_response(response, $('post'));
    }
}).send();
```